# Subclassing UIButton

Tags: ios, uiview, uibutton, subclass, uistoryboard

I would like to know if you think subclassing UIButton would be a good idea in my situation and if so how exactly to go about doing it?

So the situation is that I have three custom buttons in my project that I need in most if not all view controllers in my project. The approach I have taken at the moment is that I've built them using storyboards in all my controllers and then added functionality as needed. However, I've found that this can lead to a painful situation where even when I want to do something, like just change the height, I need to do it 8 times. So my idea was this, have 3 subclasses of uibuttons (with the required characteristics like image in different states,width,height,position etc) that I can then add to my different view controllers and then perform segues from them as and when needed. And if I need to make any changes, I will just have to do them once in the subclass as opposed to in all the view controllers.

What do you guys think?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Sure, I think this would work fine. Add custom buttons in your storyboard, and change their class to one of your button subclasses. In the subclass make your customizations in the initWithCoder: method.

Comment: I found that using `initWithCoder` instead of `initWithFrame` is critical for UIButton.

Comment: @NickM, it's not specific to UIButton, it's whether the UI element is made in IB (storyboard or xib) or code. If in the former, you need to use initWithCoder:, if the latter, use initWithFrame:.

Answer (score 0):

You can subclass the UIButton, but a better solution would be to create a Category for the UIButton

look at the tutorial: http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/iphone/custom-uibutton_iphone/